# Why dispatch inside async function does not dispatch action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Currently I want to dispatch the action inside the async function, but the action is not being dispatched? The reason for using Redux is because I want to add a like button to any images that is being filtered by the search input.

[The link to the entire App am working on....](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-dawn-khouk) *---go to file components/App.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import unsplash from '../api/unsplash';
import ImageList from './ImageList';
import { fetchImages } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { images: [] };

  onSearchSubmit = term => {  

    return async (dispatch) => {

      const response = await unsplash.get('/search/photos', {
        params:{ query: term },
        //use the path on unsplash for image searching
      })

      let success = response.data.results
      
      dispatch(fetchImages(success));
      return success;
      // this.setState({ images: response.data.results });
    }
    
  }

  render() {
    return (<div className="ui container" style={{marginTop:'10px'}}> 
      <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit}/>
      <ImageList images={this.state.images}/>
    </div>);
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

    fetchImages: images => dispatch(fetchImages(images))

})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: `dispatch` is not magic keyword, you would have to pass `dispatch` to your `App` or your function inside your App component `onSearchSubmit` so that it holds reference to `dispatch` using which you can dispatch actions in there.

Comment: Maybe you can check the added link which redirect you to codesandbox if you click on that.  @Rikin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm take more updates on your project. see codesandbox example!

```
import React from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import ImageList from "./ImageList";
import { fetchImages } from "../actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

class App extends React.Component {

  onSearchSubmit = term => {
    this.props.fetchImages(term);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
        <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
        <ImageList images={this.props.images} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    images: state.images
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    fetchImages: bindActionCreators(fetchImages, dispatch)
  })
)(App);
```

Action:

```
export function fetchImages(term) {
  return function action(dispatch, getState) {
    unsplash
      .get("/search/photos", {
        params: { query: term }
        //use the path on unsplash for image searching
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.results);
        dispatch({ type: types.FETCH_BUTTON, payload: res.data.results });
      });
  };
}
```

And state:

```
export const images = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case types.FETCH_BUTTON:
      return Object.assign([], state, [...action.payload]);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Working example:

[image: Edit angry-zhukovsky-j9qv1]

Comment: TypeError: props.images.map is not a function is the error i get from the console....

Comment: if you see my example, need to update `export const images = (state = initialState, action) => {`  to `export const images = (state = [], action) => {`

Answer (score 0):

Modifing @Fiodorov Andrei code a little.

Here is a way without bindActionCreators.

Just define function in mapDispatchToProps as "onSearchSubmit"
and dispatch action there (simple one liner :) )

```
import React from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import ImageList from "./ImageList";
import { fetchImages } from "../actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { images: [] };

  render() {
    const { onSearchSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
        <SearchBar onSubmit={onSearchSubmit} />
        <ImageList images={this.props.images} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    images: state.images
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    onSearchSubmit: term => dispatch(fetchImages(term)),
  })
)(App);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-tdd-1vrf5)

Answer (score -1):

You already mapped dispatch to your props and do not need to call  `dispatch(fetchImages())`.
Try to call that mapped function instead:
`this.props.fetchImages()`

Comment: Maybe you can check the added link which redirect you to codesandbox if you click on that.